# Could not load IDurableOrchestrationClient

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm getting started with a vanilla Durable Function but I'm encountering the exception below in Azure:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IDurableOrchestrationClient'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=014045d636e89289'.

The Azure Function is using the 3.0 runtime and the csproj is targeting .netCore 3.1. The packages that I have installed are:
Microsoft.Azure.DurableTask.AzureStorage (1.12.0)
Microsoft.Azure.DurableTask.Core (2.10.0)
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask (2.7.1)
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (3.0.13)

I'm using the IDurableOrchestrationClient in my function like this:

```
public static class Function1
{

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        
        string name = req.Query["productId"];

        log.LogInformation("Got product Id " + name);

        //string orchestrationId = await client.StartNewAsync("SyncOrchestrator", name);
        //return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, orchestrationId);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me to a sample or help me isolate the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the packageReference defined in .csproj file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue with the version of DurableTak. As you are using version 2.7.1, please use the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask i.e. [2.7.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask) which compatible with .net core 3.1 as well.

In case, if you still face the issue after upgrading the package then please let me know so we can connect offline.